# How to print dynamic copyright message using Javascript without crashing the interface with UI Initialiation Error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, primefaces

I'm developing a webpage where I want to display a dynamic string of Copyright warning. Doing some research I managed to find out a sample code which did that and, after implementing it, it seems it worked just fine. The problem is that since the implementation of that code, my webpage started to collapse everytime I returned to the first page.

Going in greater detail: when acessing the right URL, the wepage shows a login box in "center" with the copyright message in the "south" position; no problems here. After login, the user may surf the entire website without any problem. If, though, the user asks to Logout, the website crashes claiming */ UI Initialization Error The center-pane element does not exist. The center-pane is a required element.* I checked and this is the result of the call of the copyright javascript; If I comment the call and hardcode the message, the problem gets away.

Here is the code where the Javascript is called:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/css_file_1.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/css_file_2.css"/>
        <title>Product Name</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">            
            <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="100" resizable="true">
                <div id="content" >
                    <ui:insert name="content">content</ui:insert>                    
                </div>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" minSize="80" maxSize="80" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <div id="h1_left">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/pics/Logo_Company.png" height="40" width="180" />
                </div>

                <div id="h1_center_2" style="width:40%" >
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/pics/symbol.JPG" height="63"  />                      
                </div>
             </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="50" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:outputScript name="./script/currentDate.js" />
                <script language="JavaScript">
                    document.write("Copyright @www.mycompany.com.br "+ currYear());
                </script>
                <!--Copyright @www.mycompany.com.br 2018-->
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here is the Javascript function inside currentDate.js:

```
//<![CDATA[
function currYear() 
{
    var sampleDate1 = new Date();

    return (1900 + sampleDate1.getYear());
}
//]]>
```

So why does this problem occurs? And how can I do the same thing in a different way which doesn't give this problem?

Comment: Consider adding tag about the technology you are using since it doesn't seem to be a pure HTML+CSS+JS solution.

Comment: @lolbas well I'm using Java and PrimeFaces, but the first seems evident with "javascript" being mentioned and the second is AFAIK irrelevant for the problem in question; the problem isn't with a PrimeFaces component as far as I can see. Either way, I'll add PF in the tag section =)

Comment: If there is a javascript error in your code, all other javascript code that needs to be executed after this won't be executed... Please to narrow down. E.g. does the 'north' unit play a role? If not, remove it... remove all custom css etc..